# Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Drawing.Image'

Tags: vb.net, string, typeconverter

```
PictureBox1.Image = "WindowsApplication4.My.Resources.Resources._" & itemno.Text
```

Hi, i have a bunch of pictures, all numbered from (1-100) and, when the user enters a number into the "itemno" input box, the picturebox1.image changes accordingly. How do i implement something like in the code example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ResourceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager(v=vs.110).aspx) to get a resource by name.

```
PictureBox1.Image = DirectCast(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("name_of_image"), Bitmap)
```

Comment: thanks! PictureBox1.Image = DirectCast(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("_" & itemno.Text), Bitmap) did the trick!!